# How to perform custom drawing in SpriteKit?

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

There is SKShapeNode but it can't be used in conjunction with masks.

Is there an equivalent to UIView's -drawRect: or CALayer's -renderInContext: in Sprite Kit? I looked at SKSpriteNode. Don't see a way to perform custom drawing with Core Graphics functions.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 4):

Nope. There's no custom drawing in Sprite Kit in the likes of custom OpenGL or Core Graphics.

You can create textures using Core Graphics methods and filter textures with CIFilter though, in case that helps.